# passing parameter dynamically in javascript to a button event

Tags: javascript

I have a function that addRow to a table

```
function addRow(tableId,rowEle)
{
 var tab = document.getElementById(tableId);
 var hrow = tab.insertRow();
 var func = null;

 for (var j = 0; j < rowEle.length; j++) {   
  var newTD = document.createElement("TD");
  var elem = document.createElement(rowEle[j].desc);
  elem.type = rowEle[j].type;
  elem.type == "button" ? elem.value = rowEle[j].label : false;
  rowEle[j].action != undefined ? elem.setAttribute(rowEle[j].action[0],rowEle[j].action[1]): false;
  elem.style = rowEle[j].cssStyle;   
  newTD.appendChild(elem);
  hrow.appendChild(newTD); 
 }
}
```

and my declaration looks like this

```
var eobject = new Object();
eobject.desc = "input";
eobject.type = "button";
eobject.label = "+";
eobject.action = new Array("onclick","addRow('tbl1',eleme)");
eobject.cssStyle = "width : 100%; border: 0px none; background-color:lightgreen;";
eleme.push(eobject);
```

** My Working Solution **

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Attach a click event to the button that executes `addRow()`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. I did attach a click event. "eobject.action = new Array("click","addRow");". I can't seems to  pass the parameter. The bind doesn't seems to work. apply seems to execute the function directly. Thanks in advance

Comment: This would be a lot simpler using a library like jQuery. At what point do you know what you want to pass to `addRow`? You could use an `onclick` handler directly on your button `onclick="addRow(param1, param2)"`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick reply. I would know it at the point of declaration. At the point of declaration, i would specify what elements to be listed in my table and what action they would do. Please advise me on this, I think i can't use the onclick handler because i want it as general purpose as possible unless it is still possible to achieve general purpose using onclick handler. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Matthewpavkov. Followed your advice. Got it working . Thank you very much. The solution was much simpler using setAttribute

Comment: Ok, glad you got it. You should post your solution as the answer, so others can see it in the future.